# Java - TCP connection

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I am working now on simple program to send file through TCP using Java. I have a problem that I am not able to connect between computers ( I am testing application using router and local IP adresses).

I start connection by:

```
sendSocket = new Socket(sendIp, port);
```

and I am trying to recieve connection on next PC by:

```
servsock = new ServerSocket(port);  
recieveSocket = servsock.accept();
```

where 
port is 12222,
sendIp is 169.254.5.47 ( second computer that recieves)

and myIP is 192.168.0.52 ( computer that sends)

What I am doing wrong?
I always use the same port, and I see on TCPView that java app uses that port.
Maybe I assign wrong IP, or my firewall blocks somehow.

Best regards and thanks,
Chris

Comment: they don't seem to be part of the same network right?

Comment: verify the connectivity first before testing your application, since the sender and target'IP are not in the same LAN. Telnet is a handy tool for testing this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Windows network, the IP 169.254.5.47 means the host did not obtain a valid IP address from the DHCP. In a standard local network both addresses should be on the same class C range (192.168.0.*).

You have to first solve this physical issue with your network and test it using ping (each host should be able to ping the other and see replies).

Comment: You are right. I checked IP adresses on router and I was able to make connection.

Problem is that on second computer java application returns different IP than it is. I use for that: myIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

Is it possible to fix it?

Thank you, Chris